# Preventing Timing Attacks

Tags: security

It seems that [for a while](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack#Examples), the login utility on Unix systems only calculated a hash when a valid username existed; this opened a security flaw which allowed for a timing attack, as the user could tell when a username was found by the amount of time it required to generate hashed key for comparison.

This makes sense for desktop applications, but would it make sense for web applications too? I'd lean toward doing it, but is this kind of fix necessary?

For example, in a Django auth module:

```
class MyBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            return user if user.check_password(password) else None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            User().check_password(password) # is this line necessary?
            return None
```

Would the additional hash computation make sense for this scenario? If I employ rate-limiting on auth calls, does this decrease the possibility of a timing attack like this?

Comment: +1 This is a real concern. What happens if someone tries to signup with an email that already exists?

Comment: I already filter those out, that's not really what the question's about.

Comment: Exposing users is what the question is about. This can happen many different ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original timing attack, the [Tenex](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/11/01/tenex-password-bug/) attack, had nothing to do with hashing -- it worked by positioning the password so that it crossed page boundaries leading to a virtual memory cache miss.  The attacker could try a series passwords positioned so that only the first character was in the first page, and it would know that the first character matched when verification took long enough for a cache miss to have happened.  The attacker could repeat that for each character in the password.

Unless the attacker has control over fine-grained positioning of inputs in memory, no, timing attacks on passwords are not an issue, but any secret checking algo that is super-linear w.r.t. the length of the secret (>= O(length of secret)) might leak information about the password length.

If you are careful to compare all characters in the password regardless of success, then you also defeat the attack:

```
boolean match = true;
for (int i = 0; i < min(salted_from_db_length, salted_from_user_length); ++i) {
  if (salted_from_db[i] != salted_from_user[i]) {
    match = false;
    //break;  // Stopping early leaks info.
  }
}
match = salted_from_db_length == salted_from_user_length && match;
```

You should have tests that make sure that compiler optimizations don't put timing vulnerabilities back into your code.

Note, the term "timing attack" is also used in other contexts, and those can affect web applications.  For example when a system clock is used to construct a [covert channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covert_channel) between two processes that should not be able to conspire -- javascript loaded in two different origins could establish a low bandwidth channel by using an interval to check the time and looping to consume processor or not to communicate a bit.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question, and yes you should consider taking steps to ensure that the time taken to return a 'logon denied' response for an invalid username is comparable to that for a valid username with incorrect password.

Timing attacks have been used in the case where the username is known in order to discover the hash of, and eventually the password itself, by analyzing the amount of time it takes the server to do the string comparison, hence the use of a 'slow_equals' function to compare the hashes and which does not exit early on finding a mismatch.

Upon a logon failure, you should never report back whether it's the username or password that was incorrect, as doing so would aid an attacker to discover valid usernames (though you should probably inform the user why you won't tell them whether it's the username or password they got wrong, as it tends to infuriate them otherwise).

A random attacker needs to discover valid usernames, and then the passwords for them.  If you help them discover valid usernames, they are half way there.  So if they can discover valid usernames according to the time it takes your logon script to return a failure, you would be helping them.

Let's consider the process:
1. Database query to retrieve hash and salt;
2. Hash password with salt;
3. Compare retrieved hash with generated hash from supplied password.

1. Does the query exit early when it finds the matching record?  It may do if we specified UNIQUE KEY for the username column, so we probably shouldn't do that, and instead have other mechanisms in place to avoid duplication when we modify the DB.
2. Do we perform these subsequent steps if the DB query found no record?  (Does your hashing process take a little bit of time?)  It thus follows that a 'default' hash and salt should be used if the username is not matched in order to complete the process in constant time [and this is the reason for the exception handler code in the Q].
3. Use 'slow_equals' here.

An answerer here suggested that network latency variance makes this a non-issue.  I contend that an attacker does not need a 100% success rate, and that statistical analysis will be revealing.  You can't be too careful.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be a definitive answer, but it seems like you might be able to ensure that all user name checking operations took the same amount of time. Make them go into a wait state after they're finished until a predetermined amount of time has passed.

Comment: As to your primary question, though, I don't think this attack would have any affect over a network, because the return time would depend on server load, which can vary every time the request is made.